# How to convert student ID list to email address from CSV using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert a list of student IDs to email addresses using Python. I have a list of ID numbers saved as a CSV in a single 'Student ID' column which I need to convert into given university email address formats. E.g. mine is `2128654`' and I need to convert to `u2128654@live.university.ac.uk`.

Very new to Python so any help would be much appreciated please. Just learnt how to read databases using `dataframe = pd.read_csv` so this is a bit out of my league at this point.

I've tried the below which visualizes my list of IDs, but now need to add a new column, add the converted email formats to that column, then save as a new file.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("/content/Student IDs.csv")
dataframe
```

CSV looks like:

| Student ID |
| --- |
| 123456789 |
| 012345678 |
| 901234567 |
| 890123456 |

Any guidance much appreciated please!

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach using [`df.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to concatenate

```py
df['Email'] = 'u' + df['Student ID'].astype(str) + '@live.university.ac.uk'
print(df)
```

---

```
  Student ID                             Email
0  123456789  u123456789@live.university.ac.uk
1  012345678  u012345678@live.university.ac.uk
2  901234567  u901234567@live.university.ac.uk
3  890123456  u890123456@live.university.ac.uk
```

To save a new file:

```py
df.to_csv('/content/output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's worked! Thanks so much that's gonna be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to read your `csv` as `strings` since leading 0s will be removed. Then use `apply` to do the following string concatenation `u` + `Student#` + `@live.university.ac.uk`:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("/content/Student IDs.csv", dtype=str)
dataframe["Student Emails"] = test["Student ID"].apply(lambda x: "u" +x + "@live.university.ac.uk")
```

Comment: This is an edge case that should be considered!